# combobox selection changed behaviour?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am developing a WPF application in which i have a `ComboBox`,like this

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding VipCodes}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVipCode,Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxStyle}" x:Name="vipCode" >
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

after loading the page when the selection changed, i need to update a value of a property.

I did like hooking up the selection changed event and set the value.
But when the page loaded, the event fires and the value of a property is set.

how can i bypass this?

Comment: Why can't you just change the mode of binding to SelectedVipCode to TwoWay and set in in ViewModel?

Comment: @  Anton Danylov Sorry i cannot change the value of that property thats for initial setting of the selected item.

Comment: Initial selected item can be set in ViewModel constructor. Typically it such scenario you do not need deal with UI events at all. Could you please add your view model code also?

Comment: *"But when the page loaded, the event fires and the value of a property is set"* - which value is set? If it's `null`, then simply check for `null` in property setter and ignore call.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a global variable if you absolutely have to. var SkipOnce = true; and then on page load set it to false at the end. And then in your selection changed event add: if (SkipOnce==false) {  //do stuff }

Answer (score 0):

Described behavior can be achieved without event handlers in code behind, by ViewModel only. If DataContext of ComboBox is set to view model, then following code will do the job:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _vipCodes.Add(new VipCode() { Description = i.ToString() });
        }

        SelectedVipCode = _vipCodes[3];
    }

    private ObservableCollection<VipCode> _vipCodes = new ObservableCollection<VipCode>();


    public ObservableCollection<VipCode> VipCodes
    {
        get { return _vipCodes; }
    }

    private VipCode _selectedVipCode;
    public VipCode SelectedVipCode
    {
         get { return _selectedVipCode; }
        set
        {
            _selectedVipCode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
```